# ERROR: null value in column "next_nonce" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)

Tags: nodes, chainlink, docker

I am using this command to run my `chainlink node`:

```
docker run --name chainlink-kovan --network host -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.3 local n
```

But facing this error:

```
pam@g3:~/.chainlink-kovan$ docker run --name chainlink-kovan --network host -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.3 local n
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]  Starting Chainlink Node 0.10.3 at commit 5dbbc21f13fa00ee724c439273156834c45ab93e cmd/local_client.go:56  InstanceUUID=1cbe6713-c2e3-490d-89d4-b7665ad739e6 SHA=5dbbc21f13fa00ee724c439273156834c45ab93e Version=0.10.3 id=boot 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     postgres@v1.0.8/migrator.go:183 elapsed=0.521704 sql=SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = CURRENT_SCHEMA() AND table_name = 'migrations' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.281306 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '1611847145' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.210859 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0002_gormv2' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.139911 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0003_eth_logs_table' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.138896 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0004_cleanup_tx_state' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.147176 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0005_eth_tx_attempts_insufficient_eth_index' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.103328 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0006_unique_task_specs_per_pipeline_run' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.084087 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0007_reverse_eth_logs_table' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.0755 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0008_reapply_eth_logs_table' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.07415 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0009_add_min_payment_to_flux_monitor_spec' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.076459 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0010_bridge_fk' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.073493 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0011_latest_round_requested' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.073711 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0012_change_jobs_to_numeric' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.07241 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0013_create_flux_monitor_round_stats_v2' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.078909 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0014_add_keeper_tables' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [INFO]                                                     v2@v2.0.0/gormigrate.go:389 elapsed=0.161362 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0015_simplify_log_broadcaster' 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [DEBUG] P2P_PEER_ID was not set, using the first available key chainlink/application.go:299 peerID=p2p_12D3KooWEesk3exLDiVonNmYxpfc2WKyfXs7h9BVE1pxfhvTHKvo 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [DEBUG] GasUpdater: dynamic gas updates are enabled        chainlink/application.go:153 ethGasPriceDefault=15000000000 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [DEBUG] Off-chain reporting disabled                       chainlink/application.go:231 
2021-04-08T12:59:37Z [WARN]  The file /chainlink/.env is not owned by the user running chainlink. This will be made mandatory in the future. cmd/local_client.go:187 
2021-04-08T12:59:45Z [INFO]  Unlocked account 0x777C8cCaF12Bd4b11aB39B69c02D2dd00BF8a0EF store/key_store.go:76   address=0x777C8cCaF12Bd4b11aB39B69c02D2dd00BF8a0EF 
2021-04-08T12:59:46Z [INFO]  Unlocked account 0xA305E3d3a070A5d6B980442C9FeDCE6AB1509b13 store/key_store.go:76   address=0xA305E3d3a070A5d6B980442C9FeDCE6AB1509b13 
2021-04-08T12:59:47Z [DEBUG] Unlocked P2P key                                   offchainreporting/keystore.go:65 peerID=p2p_12D3KooWEesk3exLDiVonNmYxpfc2WKyfXs7h9BVE1pxfhvTHKvo 
2021-04-08T12:59:48Z [DEBUG] Unlocked OCR key                                   offchainreporting/keystore.go:72 
2021-04-08T12:59:48Z [INFO]  API exposed for user akcgjc007@gmail.com           cmd/local_client.go:105 
2021-04-08T12:59:48Z [DEBUG] eth.Client#Dial(...)                               eth/client.go:128       
2021-04-08T12:59:49Z [ERROR]                                                    orm/orm.go:1291         elapsed=3.084322 err=ERROR: null value in column "next_nonce" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502) rows=0 sql=INSERT INTO "keys" ("address","json","created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","next_nonce","last_used","is_funding") VALUES ('0x777C8cCaF12Bd4b11aB39B69c02D2dd00BF8a0EF','{"id": "febda53b-c5d4-447a-974e-fc8475c7dc2b", "crypto": {"kdf": "scrypt", "mac": "7a3eec0e1736b673eb610f3e1b14d64eb153064a5569018e43638c84d3447a7d", "cipher": "aes-128-ctr", "kdfparams": {"n": 262144, "p": 1, "r": 8, "salt": "c0e76b0b64b37b9dbd54e6dbf6ef140bfd4149632126d3147f2f88f56b03af0e", "dklen": 32}, "ciphertext": "3facef4796cebcd6de529e66ffd483e14bc27a0c319a390290512e68d04e4c95", "cipherparams": {"iv": "12db249256142f1bd5e0ee14b9bfdd60"}}, "address": "777c8ccaf12bd4b11ab39b69c02d2dd00bf8a0ef", "version": 3}','2021-04-08 12:59:49.597','2021-04-08 12:59:49.597',NULL,NULL,NULL,false) ON CONFLICT ("address") DO UPDATE SET "deleted_at"=NULL RETURNING "id" stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/orm.(*ORM).CreateKeyIfNotExists
    /chainlink/core/store/orm/orm.go:1291
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.(*Store).SyncDiskKeyStoreToDB
    /chainlink/core/store/store.go:158
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.(*Store).Start
    /chainlink/core/store/store.go:114
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.(*ChainlinkApplication).Start
    /chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:347
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
    /chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:106
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:524
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:173
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:405
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:372
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:102
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:277
main.Run
    /chainlink/core/main.go:20
main.main
    /chainlink/core/main.go:14
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204 
2021-04-08T12:59:49Z [ERROR]                                                    orm/orm.go:1291         elapsed=0.403866 err=ERROR: null value in column "next_nonce" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502) rows=0 sql=INSERT INTO "keys" ("address","json","created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","next_nonce","last_used","is_funding") VALUES ('0xA305E3d3a070A5d6B980442C9FeDCE6AB1509b13','{"id": "196af0fd-bdd4-4d67-b26a-670093f672f6", "crypto": {"kdf": "scrypt", "mac": "01b234c8033e176ebac8d517d550917a16c7d1e60f673c555a8935d56fc150c6", "cipher": "aes-128-ctr", "kdfparams": {"n": 262144, "p": 1, "r": 8, "salt": "df6e8f8b7c18ee0a1ef82a34713781dc9ce050e28dfafcb2a7ba42f943139c87", "dklen": 32}, "ciphertext": "cde4a44fff92b21721a4c4bf19169d14d990b6f3e66369b40ba0d2d44be9ad04", "cipherparams": {"iv": "8833be37955e9ddff1e773fdab770c3d"}}, "address": "a305e3d3a070a5d6b980442c9fedce6ab1509b13", "version": 3}','2021-04-08 12:59:49.602','2021-04-08 12:59:49.602',NULL,NULL,NULL,false) ON CONFLICT ("address") DO UPDATE SET "deleted_at"=NULL RETURNING "id" stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/orm.(*ORM).CreateKeyIfNotExists
    /chainlink/core/store/orm/orm.go:1291
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.(*Store).SyncDiskKeyStoreToDB
    /chainlink/core/store/store.go:158
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store.(*Store).Start
    /chainlink/core/store/store.go:114
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/chainlink.(*ChainlinkApplication).Start
    /chainlink/core/services/chainlink/application.go:347
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode
    /chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:106
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:524
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:173
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:405
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:372
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/command.go:102
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.5/app.go:277
main.Run
    /chainlink/core/main.go:20
main.main
    /chainlink/core/main.go:14
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204 
error starting app: the following errors occurred:
 -  ERROR: null value in column "next_nonce" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)
 -  ERROR: null value in column "next_nonce" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)
```

Just to mention, that I was trying to run different docker images of `smartcontract/chainlink` with the same `postgres` database.

Comment: Awesome question, could you try a different version?

Comment: As I was time bounded, I have reset the postgres server, leading to deletion of the node information.

What I suscept was, I tried to run different docker images using the same postgres database.(and I am sure different docker images would have different ways of using the postgres).

Comment: Ah, so it’s solved now?

Comment: I can try recreating the error later & update on this.